# What is the procedure to find the time complexity of python program?

Tags: loops, python

Is there any kind of function which is used in python to calculate the time complexity of another function?

Comment: Python-specific questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Your comment constitutes an answer to the question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Fair point. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity, like any other nontrivial property of programs, is undecidable: there can be no algorithm to compute it, in Python or anything else.